# Get a list of all sites user has edit rights in SharePoint 2013

Tags: permissions

We have a requirement where we have to display a list of all sites in which a user has contribute rights. We have many site collections and inside each site collection we have many sub sites. Users have contribute rights in some sites of this complete hierarchy. How can we achieve this? can we use searc, REST APIs, JSOM, CSOM or we have to use SSOM for this? If SSOM is the only option, how can we achieve it using SSOM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the current user, or any user? Also, where are you displaying these sites? On a page? Storing them to a file or a list?

Comment: Also, do you need this in real time or would a periodic job do the trick? The reason I'm asking this is because that code is going to take some time to run.

Comment: Hi Derek, I want it for the current user. Yes, we are displaying it on a page. Don't have to store them to a file or list. I need it in real time. When the user visits the home page of a site, he should see the sites from the entire web application he has edit rights. If I take the timer job approach, i have to store it somewhere. Right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this, and you'll need to do some analysis on your environment to determine what works best for you. I can think of two options: a brute force method using server-side object model and Search.

**Brute Force**

You'll need to grab a reference to each web aplication on your farm, and within each web application, enumerate each site collection, and within each site colleciton, recursively traverse the network of subwebs within each site collection, and make the necessary check. Depending on the scale and complexity of your farm, this could take more time to run than would be advisable on a typical web page. But then again, you could consider it a report, and communicate it as such to your users.

**Search**

Run a search query which returns a collection of sites. This will return all sites the current user has read access to, so you'll need to iterate those results and check for the right permission. This might run quicker but you may have sites that are set to not be indexed, so they'll be excluded from the results.

**Running a timer Job**

Doing this in a job is going to be problematic as well. There really is no way to grab a collection of all users unless you grab all the users in Active Directory, of which maybe a small subset of the accounts might or might not be SharePoint users. Then, doing a brute force approach looping over all the users - could potentially take a really long time. Then you'd need to figure out how to structure that data and where to store it.

**Things for you to consider:**

- Does this list change frequently?
- Do you use AD groups consistently, or do you assign users to sites in an unpredictable fashion? In other words, can we somehow streamline the process?
- How complex are your security configurations? Do you use broken inheritance a lot? If not, maybe you can skip the iterating subsites.
- What if a user has "Limited Access"? How do you want to handle that?

**Bottom Line**

This is not going to be easy. A lot of it depends on specific details of your environment and the complexity of the security configurations, and whether you can safely make any assumptions along the way.

**What would I do?**

I would push back on the requirement by making sure the customers understands the complexities, issues and risks involved with the implementation. Then I would whip up a simple page with a Search results web part showing only sites. This would be automatically security trimmed (although it would be scoped to read access, not contribute). You could whip this up in an hour. Your admins will love you because you won't need to deploy any code to the servers. It would get you probably 80% of the requirement for probably 1% of the development effort.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for explainining the pros and cons of every approaches. Really helpful. To answer a few questions: The list won't change frequently. However, if it is changed, they don't want much delay before the list is updated.

Comment: Haven't yet decided on using AD groups. 
The permissions for some site collections would remain same in that site collection. However, for some site collections, it will be broken at sub site level. So, I have to iterate through all the sub sites to check the permissions. You are correct, this is not going to be easy. 


The solutiuon should be cloud ready. So can't use SSOM. Have to make my way through JSOM/REST with search or CSOM in a provider hosted app.

Comment: You will not be able to use CSOM or REST unless you store a list of site collections somewhere (probably in a list), but that means you have to keep that up to date.  You will not be able to use JSOM at all, as that runs on a page and cannot break out of its site collection. Actually, if you are willing to store a list of site collections that should greatly simplify your task.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I was thinking about using search to get a list of all site collections and webs in the farm where user has read access. And then using JSOM, querying each sitecollection and site individually to see if user has edit rights on it. However, it seems it is too messy to work with JSOM async queries with so many requests. Also browser can't generate many queries at a time. Any thoughts on this? Thanks again.

Comment: Looping in JSOM is messy and error prone as you know. But your bigger problem is you can not reach outside your site collection using JSOM, so you will not be able to query other site collections as you propose. You'll have to use REST or the SOAP web services which might be marginally less messy because you can use promises.

Comment: Ok. Can't I use SP.ClientContext(url) to create a context for a different site collection? I read that getting permissions through REST is very tricky and JSOM is recommended. Your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it won't work in JSOM if the url is outside the current site collection. Give it a shot and wee what I mean. Do a web search for cross-domain calls in jQuery for REST. It's slightly more complex, but once you know it, you know it.